# CheckBox Display issue in Active Reports 10 .Net Frame work

Tags: activereports

I am using Active reports 10 in my project.
I am facing an issue with checkboxes in my project. I am unable to see the checkboxes on Html5 Viewer. Where as checkboxes are showing in the pdf file which is generated. Is there any way i can display the checkboxes on the html5 Viewer.